# Admin user role in nodejs

Tags: node.js, permissions, mongoose, roles

My web app needs 2 user roles (user and admin).I am using passport local authentication for this.

For now by adding the code below I have 2 roles but the admin's one has access to user routes too. I have to go by hand to /admin route in order to user its features.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
res.redirect('/login');
}

function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    if (req.user.local.role == "admin") {
        return next();
    }
}
res.redirect('/login');
}
```

**Now my question is how can I change isAdmin function so that when I log in as administrator I go instantly to the /admin route ?**

Answer (score 1):

user roles and access permission in expressjs. if you want to first create roles and then after create the permissions on own app the we must define first roles and then add permissions on those roles

```
var acl = require('acl');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');

acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, config.db.aclCollectionPrefix), { debug: function(string) { console.log(string); } });

module.exports = {
    init: function() {
        acl.addRoleParents('superAdmin', 'admin');
        acl.addRoleParents('admin', 'user');
        acl.allow([
            {
                roles: ['admin'],
                allows: [
                    {
                        resources: '/user/list',
                        permissions: 'get'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                roles: ['superAdmin'],
                allows: [
                    {
                        resources: '/admin/list',
                        permissions: 'get'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]);
    },

    getAcl: function() {
        return acl;
    }
};
```

here my **config** file which is defined my mongo connection and acl prefix. and after we want to define routes which may have set permissions on those routes.

**these lines to be added in admin.js file**

```
var acl = require('../authorization').getAcl();

// protected URLs
router.get('/list', acl.middleware(2, userController.getUserId), adminController.list.get);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not change the "isAdmin" function! Use something like this:

```
app.get('/admin-page', isAdmin, function(req, res) {
    res.render('admin', {         //'admin' is your admin template
        user : req.user 
       // or any other data you want to render! 
    });
});
```

Comment: I have actually done that, but when I log in with an admin account it has access to user routes too. Thnx anyway !

Comment: Admin will obviously have access to the user routes ... you are nowhere blocking access for admin in 'isLoggedIn'. These are routes functions which define the behavior when called as address. For redirection, use "res.redirect(..)"  as and when required! Please clearly mention your requirements along with full code!